# How LoadRunner can monitor resourcec of the system under test?

Tags: resources, monitoring, loadrunner

I have read that LR uses native monitors (perfmon) but how can it access it without setting anything on the tested system?
EDIT: I have just read that you set monitoring to load generator machine, which confuses me even more. How can I measure the CPU usage (e.g.) of the tested server if I activate the monitoring on load generator?

Answer (score 1):

Pleae read the monitoring guide which comes with your version of LoadRunner.   All versions of LoadRunner post version 8 include a copy of SiteScope, with a 500 point license as the default.    Information on monitoring is also covered in courses on the controller and SiteScope taught by HP's authorized training partners.

LoadRunner connects to SiteScope.   SiteScope uses the Perfmon remote procedure call interface to call into Windows servers for any PerfMon stat.   On the UNIX/LINUX Front SiteScope uses SSH or Telnet to sign onto the host and run native OS utilities to collect metrics.    Additionally, SNMP can also be used from SiteScope to interrigate not only Windows and UNIX/LINUX hosts, but any host which supports SNMP, including routers, switches, midrange and mainframe computers.   You also have the capability of interrogating native services, such as Apache, ORACLE, DB2, for platform specific stats.

If you elect not to use SiteScope, then LoadRunner supports a native Perfmon Interface, a native SNMP interface, a native RSTATD interface, a native ORACLE interface, native APACHE, etc...     You can view all of the native monitors in the monitoring section of the controller.    SiteScope is the future foundation set for monitoring.

Comment: thanks, I did read the guide. However, for LR native support, how this can connect to server and get the perfmon data?

Comment: In sitescope you provide the credentials used to interrogate the system for the perfmon remote procedure call data.   If going straight from your existing LoadRunner controller then you would leverage the security token of the existing signed on credentials for your user on the controller.   This would mean the your Controller User credentials would need to have privilieges to pull perfmon data on the remote host.   How can you tell?   Start Perfmon on the controller and then connect to the remote host for data.   If you see counters then you are good.  If not, then you need additional rights.